# My MacBook Air won't charge correctly : the light is green instead of orange

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a 2009 MacBook Air (**MacBookAir2,1**)

I have a **compatible** MagSafe and a **Apple** one.

Sometimes (almost most of the time), when the computer is running and not in sleep, if I plug the MagSafe, it goes **orange** for a few minutes then goes back to **green**. It says that the computer doesn't use battery but it doesn't charge it.

I have tried with both chargers and it is the same.

Now I have also tried to shut the computer down and charge it : it works, it remains **orange** and charges the battery.

I must admit that I have changed the battery to a compatible one because mine was too old.

Do you think the fact that it is a compatible battery makes the computer thinks it is fully loaded and stops charging ?  Is there a way to prevent that instead of stopping the computer to charge ?

Thanks

Comment: I have changed my battery back to the original Apple one and it works correctly. Seems the third-party battery is not good even after SMC Reset.

Comment: I have ordered a new third party battery and I'll try with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).  According to Apple, one of the reasons to reset your SMC is...

[image]

**To do a reset**

1. Shut down the Mac.
2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your Mac.
3. Using the built-in keyboard, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> on the left side of the keyboard, then press the power button at the same time.
   Release all keys, then press the power button again to turn on your Mac

If you continue to have problems, I would then run an [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and see if you can obtain any diagnostic info.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unlikely case, but this is what happened to me. If the voltage/power of what the charger is plugged into is not sufficient enough to charge your computer, the light will be green and/or 'Not Charging' will be displayed in the menu bar. This happened to me on the plane. I use a pretty powerful laptop.